# Reading output data from COM port using C++

Tags: c++

i have a board and a GPS,accelerometer,gyroscope onboard. 
I'm connecting the board to the computer by using a TTL-232R-3V3 ,which is a USB to TTL Serial Cable (3.3V).
After installing the drivers, the assigned COM port is the number 3.
I'm able to read the output simply by using a serial monitor (i've tried with the one included in the Arduino IDE, just for try).

Now i need to create a C++ program which allows me to take the output of the board and store the datas in vectors.
Do i need any libraries? What's the best procedure to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [A dedicated library seems the best approach](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial)

Comment: "How do I make <entire program>" is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

In my company I used the boost library to read from a COM port. It includes the `boost::asio::serial_port` class to handle this kind of communication.

I used this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/yoggy/3323808) for orientation and wrote my own wrapper class, for the needs of the project I was in.

Answer (score 0):

You can take this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C

Or if you use Qt, i think there is also a lib from Qt to do this.